# How to resolve ambiguity when argument is null?

Tags: c#, null, ambiguous-call

Compiling the following code will return `The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties` error. How to resolve it since I can't explicitly convert `null` to any of those classes?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Func(null);
}

void Func(Class1 a)
{

}

void Func(Class2 b)
{

}
```

Comment: oh, sorry, looks like I can :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
Func((Class1)null);
```

Answer (score 12):

You could also use a variable:

```
Class1 x = null;
Func(x);
```

Comment: +1 This method is easier to read and understand than func((Class1)null). Casting null is not intuitive.

Comment: This is preferable to casting wherever possible, as it catches many problems at compile time that would otherwise be runtime cast errors.

Answer (score 11):

Cast `null` to the type:

```
Func((Class1)null);
```

Answer (score 10):

Using `as` for the casting makes it slightly more readable with the same functionality.

```
Func(null as Class1);
```

Answer (score 4):

The `Func()` methods accept a reference type as a parameter, which can be null. Since you're calling the method with an explicit `null` value, the compiler doesn't know whether your null is supposed to be in reference to a `Class1` object or a `Class2` object.

You have two options:

Cast the null to either the `Class1` or `Class2` type, as in `Func((Class1)null)` or `Func((Class2)null)`

Provide a new overload of the `Func()` method that accepts no parameters, and call that overload when you don't have an explicit object reference:

```
void Func()
{
    // call this when no object is available
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to cast null to either of those, the same as you would a variable `Func((Class1)null)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative solution I prefer

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Func(Class1.NULL);
}

void Func(Class1 a)
{ }

void Func(Class2 b)
{ }

class Class1
{
    public static readonly Class1 NULL = null;
}

class Class2
{
    public static readonly Class2 NULL = null;
}
```