# Overloading null ambiguity

Tags: c#, methods, overloading

I have the following methods:

```
  void Method(string param1, string param2);
  void Method(string param1, object param2);
```

When I call the method using the following:

```
  method("string", null);
```

It gives me an error because the call is ambiguous, the compiler does not know which version to call, because both methods accept `null` as the second parameter.

How do I overcome this without changing the method name in one of them? the first method will never have `null`.

Comment: Either can certainly have null; but an easy way to call a specific one with null is to make a null variable of the specific type.

Comment: Try calling it like: method("string", (string)null); or method("string", (object)null);

Comment: Which version of .NET are you use. Because there is no ambiguity. The specification is very clear on overload resolution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resolve ambiguity when argument is null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044055/how-to-resolve-ambiguity-when-argument-is-null)

Comment: @HamletHakobyan .Net 4.0

Comment: No ambiguity is raised. All works fine.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan well, I do not know what language are you using, but in C# and .NET 4.0 it does raise an error indeed.

Comment: As @HamletHakobyan said, your example should not lead to ambiguity. That is because every `string` is an `object`, but not every `object` is a `string`, so it is not symmetrical, and in that case the "most specific" overload, here `Method(string, string)` is preferred. Your real scenario is probably different. For example if the overloads were `Method(string, string)` and `Method(string, Uri)`, it _would_ be ambiguous.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is that both `string` and `object` are nullable, so `null` could refer to either overload of the method. You have to cast the null value—as stupid as that sounds—to say explicitely which overload you want to call.

```
method("string", (string) null);
method("string", (object) null);
```

This is basically the same as if you defined a variable of either type and passed that then:

```
string param1 = null;
object param2 = null;

method("string", param1); // will call the string overload
method("string", param2); // will call the object overload
```

Both `param1` and `param2` have the same value, `null`, but the variables are of different types which is why the compiler is able to tell exactly which overload it needs to use. The solution above with the explicit cast is just the same; it annotates a type to the `null` value which is then used to infer the correct overload—just without having to declare a variable.

Comment: Thanks.. is this like a hack? or is it a common way of overcoming this issue?

Comment: No, it’s not a hack. It’s just telling the compiler explicitely which overload you want to call by saying explicitely which version you are referring to.

Comment: This way will at least allow you to avoid R# warnings, as opposed to my preferred way of just using a `string empty = null;` etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can be specific about which version of the method you want to call by specifying which type of null you're passing:

```
Method("string", null as string);
```